# Crystal Report Image Issue

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, crystal-reports-xi

Crystal Report......Web Application MVC

I am trying to get Image to displayed. 
Logo of company instead it is showing `image alt="Image"`. By checking inspecting element I came to know that the `src="CrystalImageHandler.aspx?dynamicimage=cr_tmp_image_d6cbdac3-0385-4ffd-a368-5a514303cb66.png"`
. I tried hard to get it rectified by searching on many sites but could get...

any one who know this issue...

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have struggled with similar issue for quite some time.

I hope this solution might help you.

Web Config Changes:

```html
    <httpHandlers>
      <add verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler.aspx" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" />
    </httpHandlers>


    <handlers>
      <remove name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" />
      <add name="CrystalImageHandler.aspx_GET" verb="GET" path="CrystalImageHandler" type="CrystalDecisions.Web.CrystalImageHandler, CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.3500.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692FBEA5521E1304" preCondition="integratedMode"/>
    </handlers>
```

```
Note*: Handler Path field didn't had ".aspx" extension.
```

Add this block of code to you global.asax.cs

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var p = Request.Path.ToLower().Trim();
        if (p.EndsWith("/crystalimagehandler.aspx") && p != "/crystalimagehandler.aspx")
        {
            var fullPath = Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.ToLower();
            var NewURL = fullPath.Replace(".aspx", "");
            Response.Redirect(NewURL);
        }
    }
```

This would Help you to resolve the issue.